# For loops with csv columns (panda)

Tags: pandas, loops, csv, for-loop

Hey guys i'm very new with python and I would like to create a for loop so I can access all columns of a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Without the loop I would have to write a line to access each column individually:

```
y2 = df.iloc[:, 2]
y3 = df.iloc[:, 3]
y4 = df.iloc[:, 4]
```

But I would like to make a loop so I don't have to type all.

I have tried this :

```
for x in range (1, 500):
    y = df.iloc[:, x]
```

But it clearly does not work.

I am very new to python, please be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone on reddit r/learnpython gave me the perfect answer :

```
ys = [df.iloc[:, x] for x in range(0, 500)]
```